# Django - How to create sub entries for each object in Models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Example:

```
Item Version S#
abc1  abc1V   abc1S#
abc2  abc2V   abc2S#
```

Model

```
class Hw(models.Model):
        item= models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
        version= models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
        serianlnumber= models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
```

now abc2 item has subitems and it has its subitems in it with their respective Versions and S#s

```
Item            Version          S#
abc2            abc2V            abc2S#
 abc2sub1        abc2sub1V         abc2sub1S# 
   abc2sub_sub1      abc2sub1V         abc2sub1S# 
abc3            abc3V            abc3S#
```

How do i create model/table like that or do i need to create different tables for each sub entries ? I could not find any specific documentation on this. Thanks

Comment: For tree-like data, you can use `django-mptt` https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt or `django-treebeard` https://github.com/django-treebeard/django-treebeard This will likely be more convenient that writing your own tree-like management software.

Comment: Thank you, looking this up now. Looks like this is exactly what i need,